# Rendering map with 'googlemaps' package

Tags: meteor

I'm using the `googlemaps` package and I'm unable to get the map to render.

`main.html` contains:

```
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

and `main.js` contains:

```
GoogleMaps.init(
    { ... });
```

Everything is set correctly (API Key, mapOptions, etc.) but the map is not rendering. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this does not work is when the JS runs, the HTML may not be drawn yet. This style should work instead which waits for the DOM to be drawn, then inits the map.

```
<body>
    {{>mapTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="mapTemplate">
     <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</template>
```

Then your JS

```
Template.mapTemplate.rendered = function() {
    GoogleMaps.init(
    { ... });
}
```

An alternative to not splitting your map into `mapTemplate` is to init your map in the `UI.body.rendered` [callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_body)

Comment: I've tried both methods and still no rendering. Also, there are no errors.

Comment: Have you added CSS for your map so that it uses up space? (or else its not visible). If there are no Errors it might be worth looking at the Webkit dev network tab to see if the tiles are requested

Comment: Give you gmap div some height and width via css. #map-canvas { height: 100px; width: 100px }